# Jpeg image saving to db in bigger size in C#

Tags: c#, image

I am saving an image to db with keeping 100% quality in mind. To maintain the quality I'm using following method.

```
public static byte[] ImageToByteArray(Image imageIn)
{
    var qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 100L);
    var encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
    encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;
    using (var msStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        imageIn.Save(msStream, GetEncoderInfo("image/png"), encoderParams);
        return msStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

And for retriving the image from db I'm using a handler and using this following method.

```
public void AddStampOnImage(Image img, HttpContext context)
{

    Image modiFiedImage = GetScaledImage(img, resizeWidth, resizeHeight);
    int width = modiFiedImage.Width;
    int height = modiFiedImage.Height;
    int compressionLevel = 100;

    Image bitmapImg = new Bitmap(width, height, modiFiedImage.PixelFormat);
    if (modiFiedImage.PixelFormat.ToString().Contains("Indexed"))
        bitmapImg = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);


    PropertyItem[] propItems = img.PropertyItems;

    foreach (var item in propItems)
    {
        PropertyItem pItem = img.GetPropertyItem(item.Id);
        bitmapImg.SetPropertyItem(pItem);
    }

    Graphics oGraphic = Graphics.FromImage(bitmapImg);
    oGraphic.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
    oGraphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    oGraphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    oGraphic.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
    Rectangle oRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
    oGraphic.DrawImage(modiFiedImage, oRectangle);

    int x;
    int y;
    Image watermarkImg = Image.FromFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/images/" + watermarkimage + ""));
    GetWatermarkPlacement(oGraphic.DpiX, oGraphic.DpiY, width, height, watermarkImg, out x, out y);
    oGraphic.DrawImageUnscaled(watermarkImg, x, y);
    oGraphic.Dispose();
    watermarkImg.Dispose();

    long[] quality = new long[1];

    quality[0] = compressionLevel;

    EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters();
    EncoderParameter encoderParam = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, quality);
    encoderParams.Param[0] = encoderParam;

    ImageCodecInfo[] arrayICI = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
    ImageCodecInfo jpegICI = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayICI.Length; i++)
    {
        if (arrayICI[i].FormatDescription.Equals("JPEG"))
        {
            jpegICI = arrayICI[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    SetImageCacheability(context);
    bitmapImg.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, jpegICI, encoderParams);

    encoderParam.Dispose();
}
```

The problem here is in some cases it works fine meaning for 800kb image can be retrived in 700-750kb but in some cases I save 400kb image and it retrives by 800-1000kb image. I don't want this 2nd scenario to happen. What am I missing here?

Comment: You cannot. It basically means that some images you are saving are already compressed with a lower setting. Compressing them with a higher setting yields in a size increase but not in quality. Images which had a higher quality setting before compression are smaller because your compression is lower than the original. That is indeed a tricky problem.

Comment: You're saving as "image/png" in the first code snippet - are you comparing that with the size of a jpeg? png is a losless format, and may offer better compression than jpeg at 100% (jpeg is a lossy format, and optimized around that).

Comment: I'm using "image/png" because I thought jpeg is a lossy format and png is not thus saving it in a better quality don't know if its right or wrong!

Comment: @nazmoonnoor I think png is the right choice - but regarding your question, are you comparing the file size of the png with the size of the jpeg you create in the second snippet?

Comment: Could you simply save *original* image (file)? This way you don't loose anything, nor gain extra.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis - Yes but don't know if it will make any difference cause I tried with "image/jpeg" and still 2nd scenario happens.